# OpenMDAOv1+: Can parameter values of a component or group be set without the IndepVarComp component?

Tags: openmdao

Is there a way of passing design variable values to an OpenMDAO `Problem`, `Group`, or `Component` without using the `IndepVarComp` component? I have found that doing `prob.root.myComp.x = x` does not throw an error, but does not seem to be visible to the driver.

The motivation is to simplify using models created with OpenMDAO so that fewer components and connection statements are needed in the calling scripts.

Comment: Do you just want to set a static value for a param in a component?  If so, `prob['myComp.x'] = x` should work after setup has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `prob['myComp.x'] = x` and omit the `IndepVarComp` provided that you don't intend for that variable to be driven by the driver in `prob`. Any param that doesn't have an `IndepVarComp` is seen by an OpenMDAO problem as merely a constant.

If you want the driver to set the variable though, then the IndepVarComp is required.

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick. The comment from @RobFalck was also key (setup() must be called first).